# Get Object from reference Id

Tags: java

is it possible to get an object from his reference id?

i get a list of String containing the reference id of an object like:

> com.test.test.business.model.Gamma@20

how to get the object from this reference id?

it's only a string and it isn't castable to the object itself

Comment: This what you received in that list is probably because of some bug, you really should find the source of those information.

Comment: It is probably output of `toString` method. And the answer is no.

Comment: no it's not the output of a toString() method, it's the return of a rich:pickList valueChangeListener event.getNewValue(), seem that it's returning only List of Strings

Comment: @MarcoFaion change your list `List<String>` to `List<Gamma>`

Comment: i've List<Gamma> but the return value of the getNewValue() is ever a List<String>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see is called the default [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) of an object. It is an amalgamation of the FQCN (fully qualified class name) of the class it belongs to and the hashCode of the object.

Quoting from the JavaDoc of toString:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

In short, you can't get an object using this *reference id*.

We can override `toString` to give a more human readable output. Take a look at the below two classes, with and without `toString`. Try to execute the main method and compare the output of the two print statements.

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + this.name + "]";
    }
}

class Address {
    private String town;
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        Address address = new Address();

        System.out.println("Person is : " + person);
        System.out.println("Address is : " + address);
    }
}
```

However, if you are really looking for a way to persist objects and resurrect them at a later stage, you should read up on [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java).

Comment: Add to class Gamma: `@Override public String toString() { return somthing; }`.